# Android Studio Hardware Acceleration on AMD processor

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, emulation

Since I had taken Android Studio, I have a lot of errors + my emulator does not work. Everytime I try to fix my errors on YT or Google but it seems like my pc does not cooperate. I have some screenshots and I am looking for your help. I am really confused and I dont know what to do.
  Overall, i'm looking to run Android Emulator inside Android Studio, but an emulator requires Hardware Acceleration. Android studio guide me to install the intel hardware acceleration tool, but I'm running on amd ryzen 3 so that wouldn't work. Next, I tried installing an emulator with the armeabi-v7a system image which should be for non-intel machines, but that doesn't work either. I really don't know what is causing all this problem. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZueDW.png) is from running a normal ADB:

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwFeO.png) is from running an armeabi-v7a based ADB, I'm stuck with the adb interface running but not booting.

And finally, if I press the virtual power button multiple times after a while, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AisZs.png) error.

Comment: How long did you wait? Booting up the emulator can take a few minutes.

Comment: Adding some value to the above comment, in addition to the emulator boot taking a bit of time, the first ever boot can take longer than that. Just wait a bit more and see if any android logo shows up. Also, have a look at [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html).

Comment: Hy man. I`ve waited 15minutes the first time, and the second time i was thinking to let it 30minutes and si o did, but still, no booting into android on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows user:

- Check that you processor support hyper-v.
- Update Windows 10 to version 1803 or higher
- Uninstall HAXM installer from SDK tools
- Enable virtualization in BIOS of you PC, its named IOMMU or VT
- Follow the instruction from Microsoft to enable [hyper-v](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin&pivots=windows)

Run emulator on full speed )